# Error migration when user changes beetwen two frontends servers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two frontends servers with a Load Balancer and one Database.

Sometimes users change from one frontend server to the second (automatic action of the LoadBalancer).

When it arrives, an error is generate but transparent for the user

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: La séquence ne contient aucun
 élément correspondant. à
 System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
 predicate) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.DiffAssociations(ReferentialConstraint
 referentialConstraint1, ReferentialConstraint referentialConstraint2,
 ICollection`1 renamedColumns) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass1e4.<FindAddedForeignKeys>b__1df(Tuple`2
 at) à System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListItera tor`2.MoveNext() à
 System.Linq.Enumerabl e.<ConcatIterator>d__59`1.MoveNext() à
 System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() à
 System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__59`1.MoveNext() à
 System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) à
 System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata
 source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator,
 MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String
 sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument
 sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1
 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator
 migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String
 targetModelVersion) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument
 model, DbMigration lastMi gration) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
 targetMigration) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
 mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) à
 System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
 targetMigration) à
 System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext
 context) à
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
 action) à
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
 à System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput
 input) à
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
 action) à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Ge
 tEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) à
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() à
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) à
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) à
 System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T,TProperty](IQueryable`1
 source, Expression`1 path)
```

But I do not understand why:  the twos servers are the same, with the same soution and the same DLLs.

Comment: Are you sure this is because of the load balancing? How do you know? Judging from the error message, you are doing a .First() on a collection that simply has no items.

Comment: I have only one Database so the collection is not empty. But I know that this user used the 1st Frontend Server and after he used the2d front end server.

Comment: Without seeing more code, I think it's impossible to determine what the problem is exactly.

Comment: My project is huge and the problem appears on many fonctions, it is impossible to show you Code ...